Replit background jobs deployment
I built a web app in replit deployed with autoscale vm, but some outbound api calls take minutes to run, and I want to run them in the background so they don't stop if the user closes the page. The APIs return files.
The easiest would be for a Reserved VM to connect to the same db and object storage as the autoscale web app.
But the Replit Object Storage API can't access another deployment bucket, and the APIs I'm calling return files.
I could store the files temporarily in the database, but its not ideal.
What is the easiest solution? Its very common for web apps to need background jobs.
There many ways I could solve this with external services, but I want to stick to the replit ecosystem so I can build similar apps very quickly without spending ANY extra time on setup.
